# substitution in order to find the probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was wondering how do you find the density function of a random variable $Y$ given that :

$X$ is an arbitrary random variable.

$Y := X^2$

I know how to do that for the case where $X$ is continuous. But how would you that in the discrete case?

In the continuous case you would search for $ P(Y \leq y ) = P( X^2 \leq y ) $, and then when you found the distributition function, you just have to derivate it. But without this precious tool, what are the ways to conclude ?

Comment: But in the discrete case you just have $P(Y =y) = P(X^2 = y)$. You don't need to use the distribution function $P(Y \leq y)$.

Comment: so the result is simply given by $P(Y = y) = P(X^2 = y) = P(X = +/- \sqrt y) $ ?

Comment: It's even easier in the discrete case. For example, if you want to find the probability of $P(Y=a)$, you know that it's equal to $P(Y=a)=P(X=-\sqrt{a})+P(X=+\sqrt{a})$